# Cannot explain special overflow behavior

Tags: css

Consider the following code:

CSS

```
.logo {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#logo_style {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.test {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="logo">
     <div id="logo_style">
          <img src="img/pencil.png" height="300">
     </div>     
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

and the output:
[image]

If I omit overflow:auto in .test I get this:
[image]

which is what I was expecting for both cases. Can anyone give me an explanation of the different behavior when overflow:auto exists?

http://jsfiddle.net/60nzadLz/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/kgypo14y/

Thank you

Comment: without actual code I can give a best guess... If you can provide a jsfiddle I could actually test this. I ask you to because it will make sure I make no changes what so ever to the code that would return differently. But my best guess is that the `overflow:auto` is causing it to hide behind the pencil even though it shouldn't. Again this is a guess. Not sure why it would do this at all... `overflow:auto` is unnecessary any way so I'm not sure why you put it in the first place.

Comment: hungerstar - can you provide a fiddle?